# Wkhtmltopdf remove ToC from PHP exec

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm creating a PDF using WkHtmlToPdf and it is working great.

On PDFs I create there is the Table of Contents that reports every `<h>` tags I'm using in HTML.

Is it possible to say to WkHtmlToPdf to ignore the ToC creation or to ignore `<h>` tags?

This is the code I'm currently using to create PDF:

```
$command = $wkPath." sample.html $savePath\\$PdfName 2>&1";
exec("$command", $output);
```

Comment: The real question is, why are there incorrect tags in the HTML to begin with.

Comment: From what I can see in the manual, the ToC will only be generated if you explicitly enable it. Could you post `$wkPath` and/or an (simplified!) sample PDF & the corresponding HTML?

Comment: @tillz `$wkPath = "". dirname(__FILE__) . "\\..\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf";` this is the content of $wkPath. I'll try to retrieve HTML.

Comment: @tillz and this is the HTML http://pastebin.com/9HxYaFGg (there are a lot of rows that you can ignore at the end of the page because it's JS)